# UI Stress Testing on Android

Tags: android, user-interface, stress-testing, monkeyrunner

is there a way for me to do a sort of UI Stress test, similar to that of monkey runner.

I want my stress tester to click randomly on the screen until something is prompted.

however, i want to be able to detect if a dialog box comes up, then i want to put in some values, or if there is a prompt for me to upload something, i'll upload a random picture. Monkey runner does not have the functionality of knowing what dialog boxes come up right? This stress tester that i am trying to configure has to be a one size fits all stress tester.

Answer (score 1):

The monkey itself doesn't know what your UI is showing, but your app does. You might find the [`isUserAMonkey`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey%28%29) API useful. While its existence has been a source of amusement for many, it exists for these cases where you want your app to behave differently for a monkey than for a real user.

Comment: i don't quite understand? I need like if an edit text field comes up, i want monkey to spring up the keyboard and type some stuff in, then press OK

Comment: To put it another way, one option is to mock your input dialogs if `isUserAMonkey` returns true and use special testing data instead of data from user input.

Comment: ooh ok i see where you're coming from, but i need to develop something that works for all apps. What if i have to stress test an application that doesn't have the isUserAMonkey check? Also, it's supposed to stress test itself without me even touching the application. So it does random clicks on the screen and only if a dialog box appears then it does something else

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/). It also supports black-box UI testing of Android applications.

Comment: doesn't robotium only work with emulators? I need this to work on real android phones too!

Comment: I have personally used it for emulator only. I believe you can as it says on their WIKI page that 


**"Can I use Robotium on pre-installed applications?

Yes you can if you have a rooted phone."**

[link](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could try to do this with [testobject.com](http://testobject.com):

[image]

The function randomInput(...) is invoking the Exerciser Monkey. It's not completely bullet-proof, but might do the trick in your case.